# Battery powered vending machine. Possible or a pipe dream?

Tags: power-supply, battery-operated

Is it possible to power a vending machine with some form of battery power for a 24 hour period!

Info I have on vending machines:

Most run on 115 V at 10.5 A.
Power usage is estimated at 3.1 - 4.4 kWh/day for lighting and 3.5 - 4 kWh/day for refrigeration.

Comment: 10kWh of batteries (plus a margin) and an inverter? Similar size battery to that of an electric car.

Comment: You need to elaborate more about other constraints of the problem. For example, are you using a normal vending machine, or can you make your own and super insulate it (i.e. no glass windows, product can be inside very good insulation). If making your own, can you use other forms of energy like dry ice for the refrigeration and batteries for the mechanical and electronics?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, its just a fridge with a small amount of electronics in it.

If your vending machine did not have a fridge in it then the battery supply would last a lot longer (weeks).

A 12V battery bank made of deep cycle lead acid batteries and a 12v - 115v converter used in cars and caravans would do the trick.

Not think its really viable, as the batteries weigh a ton and the setup would be expensive considering the profit margins from lending machines is not high.

Comment: look up off grid power sources on google

Comment: Like other already said, your off the shelf commercial vending machine is no built for energy efficiency. If you had the products super insulated, the power required would drop significantly. Also, running lighting inside the refrigerator, 1960's style - super inefficient.